# How can I get the list of dependencies of cmake target?

Tags: cmake

For instance, how can I know if my executable target E depends on my library target L?

Let's image E depends on L1 and L2, but I don't know if they depend on L.

> target_link_libraries(E L1 L2)

I'd like to get the list from CMake itself before calling `target_link_libraries`, so that I can do some tricks if I detect that E depends on two libraries which are incompatible. I played a bit with `GetPrerequisites`, but this finds out dependencies on existing libraries which are on disk, not on target which are being built.

thanks

Comment: Just came across your question and wanted to hint to [Recursive list of LINK_LIBRARIES in CMake](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32756195/recursive-list-of-link-libraries-in-cmake) and [Retrieve all link flags in CMake](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34165365/retreive-all-link-flags-in-cmake). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 41):

You can use CMake's "dependency graphs generator". Please read this link for [details](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/cmake/Graphviz)

```
cmake --graphviz=test.dot . ...
```

Comment: To run this from within your `CMakeLists.txt` file, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42577803/3987854).

Comment: It's not working on my setup,  this show no dependencies (no arrow between nodes) where my code obviously have

Comment: The ``--graphviz`` option only considers executable and library targets but *not* custom targets (as documented). So it's not always helpful.

Comment: This does not answer the question as posed in the title, which is to get a _list_ of dependencies (i.e., not a graph).

Comment: This is really helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 13):

While graphviz output likely is more intuitive, sufficiently equivalent functionality can be enabled via a simple

```
set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY GLOBAL_DEPENDS_DEBUG_MODE 1)
```

[GLOBAL_DEPENDS_DEBUG_MODE cmake.org help](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_gbl/GLOBAL_DEPENDS_DEBUG_MODE.html)

Comment: Thanks! This is certainly helpful in many situations. Any chance I can make this work on a file-granularity (including header files)?

Answer (score 2):

I have a top level project, which contains several external sub-projects. In the CMakeLists.txt file,
most of the targets are customized and not listed
in the graph by default. Looking into the document
at https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CMakeGraphVizOptions.html, and it says,

> GRAPHVIZ_CUSTOM_TARGETS
> Set to TRUE to include custom targets in the generated graphs.
>
> Mandatory: NO
>
> Default: FALSE

To turn it on, write a file CMakeGraphVizOptions.cmake,
and put the following line in it,

> SET(GRAPHVIZ_CUSTOM_TARGETS TRUE)

Wish this helps.