# Is there a way to manually remove a dependency?

Tags: qt, cmake

I'm using CMake with [cotire](https://github.com/sakra/cotire) and Qt, and there's a bug that I'm working around. The gist of it is that I have a target, `qtwallet_unity`, which depends on `qtwallet_unity_automoc`. However, I instead need it to depend on `qtwallet_automoc`. I've done:

```
add_dependencies(qtwallet_unity qtwallet_automoc)
```

But is there any way to remove the dependency on `qtwallet_unity_automoc`? Something like:

```
*remove_dependencies(qtwallet_unity qtwallet_unity_automoc)
```

Comment: Why cannot you remove the line were the offending dependency is added in the first place? Your question seems pretty tough, for example added dependencies do not seem to be among the target properties http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-properties.7.html#properties-on-targets Somebody asked a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22021312/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-dependencies-of-cmake-target) but there was no "definitive" answer...

Comment: @Antonio: cotire is the one adding the dependency, so that'd mean me having to muck around with cotire, which I'd rather avoid doing. Ultimately that'll be the best solution - to patch cotire to fix the bug.

Comment: This should be fixed in cotire [1.7.0](https://github.com/sakra/cotire/releases/tag/cotire-1.7.0).