# How do I list the defined make targets from the command line?

Tags: cmake

I feel almost silly for asking this but I couldn't find anything on this...

Suppose I have a `cmake` project containing a number of targets (libraries, executables, external targets, etc).  How do I list them using the `cmake` command line interface?

I want a list of things that are valid to substitute for `$target` in the following command line:

```
cmake . && cmake --build . --target $target
```

**Lot's** of bonus points for a solution that uses neither `grep` nor `find` nor `python` nor `perl` nor... you get the idea.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

For Makefile generator build environments you could use

```
cmake --build . --target help
```

And there is the graphical output solution (example found [here](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake/Examples#Dependency_Graph)):

```
cmake --graphviz=test.graph 
dotty test.graph
```

See also [Generating Dependency Graphs with CMake](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/Graphviz) and [CMake Graphviz Output Cleaner](https://www.semipol.de/software/cmake-graphviz-output-cleaner).

If you don't have `dotty` installed, you can still make the target dependencies visible with enabling [GLOBAL_DEPENDS_DEBUG_MODE](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/prop_gbl/GLOBAL_DEPENDS_DEBUG_MODE.html) in your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY GLOBAL_DEPENDS_DEBUG_MODE 1)
```

The disadavantage here is that you can't trigger it from the command line. It will always show on `stderr` when generating the make environment.

**References**

- [How can I get the list of dependencies of cmake target?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22021312/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-dependencies-of-cmake-target)
- [Internet Archive: "CMake: list of targets"](https://web.archive.org/web/20160405081525/https://root.cern.ch/blog/cmake-list-targets)

Comment: Well, it would be nice to have something that is agnostic of the underlying generator but make works for me. I don't really like the graphical output solution since it requires dotty which I consider worse than perl, grep and bash because it doesn't come in the default installation of any system I use. I'll still award the points for the make-based solution.

Comment: Thanks. I've added information for using the  `GLOBAL_DEPENDS_DEBUG_MODE` global property. That will work without `dotty` and even without the `--graphviz` command line option. And - because I was also missing this in CMake before - I'm planning to post a feature request for a `--list-all-targets` command line option on CMake's bug tracker. I'll keep you updated here if I get positive feedback.

Comment: Note that ``cmake --build . --target help`` is basically the same as ``make help``

Comment: @Ignitor Yes, it's an abstraction so you don't need to know the `make` call syntax or the [make program's path](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM.html). I used it here because it also works with other "makefile generators" like `nmake`, `gmake`, `ninja`, ...

Comment: @Florian: Your second link seems to be down :-(

Comment: @MichaelKopp Thanks for the hint. I've updated the link to point to the internet archive (since this particular block post was removed).

Comment: Any generator-independent options? Looking for msbuild, specifically.

Comment: Can you tweak your answer so as to clarify in which directory one needs to run which command? Or instead, to specify the source and the build directories?

Comment: My testing shows that with cmake v 3.21, `cmake -B <build_dir> --target help` works for at least the generators: `Unix Makefiles`, `Ninja`, `Ninja Multi-Config` and possibly others.

Answer (score 20):

I think you might be looking for the command `make help`.

When I run `make help` (after running `cmake ..`) I get the following output:

```
The following are some of the valid targets for this Makefile:
... all (the default if no target is provided)
... clean
... depend
etc
```

You could also read the `Makefile` that cmake auto-generates for you.

Comment: this also (like the accepted answer) only works when the cmake generator is set to makefiles, which is the default on linux, but for osx or windows cmake uses xcode or visual studio as default generator respectively. And on linux we tend to prefer ninja, it does multi-threading builds by default and can be used to generate compile_commands.json from.

Answer (score 3):

Answer by @Florian is correct. Just to give some context to it, the command

`cmake --build . --target help` is assuming your build directory is at current directory, as indicated by the "dot".

If you set your build directory to another directory other than current directory, let say, `/build`, then you should specify it as
`cmake --build build --target help`.

Alternatively, you can also

```
cd build
make help
```

Answer (score 1):

We may get all targets of the generated Makefile, as @Florian and @Olivia Stork answered.

However, people may just looking for explicitly declared targets in CMakeLists.txt . Targets like "all" and "clean" may not be what people is interested in.

Thus, they can simply query "Built target" in the output of make.

i.e.

```sh
cd ~/work/my_project
mkdir build && cd build && cmake ..
make -j4 > log.txt 2>&1
grep 'Built target' log.txt | awk '{print $4}'
```