# Which libraries are available to link in cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake, react-native-hermes

I was learning CMake for a project and feel confused when linking libraries.

I find it easier to ask with an example, as using terms I am not familiar could be misleading.

The questions are (also commented in the example codes)

1. how can I know what are the library name I can link to my target? Can I tell that from the build file structure, or I need to look into CMakeLists.txt of the external libraries. (e.g. the gtest-main and libhermes in the example)
2. How can I use a "grandchild" library that is part of the external library?  (e.g. the jsi library in the example)

**Example**

Let's say I am writing some tests with dependency on the [Hermes Library](https://github.com/facebook/hermes). I then write a CMakeList.txt file like

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(mytests_cxx)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

include(FetchContent)

FetchContent_Declare(
  hermes
  URL https://github.com/facebook/hermes/archive/d63feeb46d26fe0ca7e789fc793f409e5158b27f.zip
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(hermes)

enable_testing()

add_executable(
  hello_test
  ./test.cpp
)

find_library (
  LIB_HERMES
  hermes # <- how can I know what is the name?
)


find_library (
  LIB_JSI
  jsi # <- How could I use a "grandchild" dependency, it is defined here (https://github.com/facebook/hermes/tree/main/API/jsi/jsi)
)

target_link_libraries(
  hello_test
  gtest_main <- Hermes seems to use gtest, how could make sure gtest_main is available?
  LIB_HERMES
  LIB_JSI
)

include(GoogleTest)
gtest_discover_tests(hello_test)
```

Running cmake to build

```
cmake -S . -B build -DHERMES_BUILD_SHARED_JSI=ON // I see an option defined in heremes'CMakeLists.txt but not sure if I am using it right.
```

the directory in build

```
tree ./build -L 2
./build
├── CMakeCache.txt
├── CMakeFiles
│   ├── 3.23.1
│   ├── CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake
│   ├── CMakeError.log
│   ├── CMakeOutput.log
│   ├── CMakeRuleHashes.txt
│   ├── CMakeTmp
│   ├── Makefile.cmake
│   ├── Makefile2
│   ├── Progress
│   ├── TargetDirectories.txt
│   ├── cmake.check_cache
│   ├── hello_test.dir
│   └── progress.marks
├── CTestTestfile.cmake
├── ImportHermesc.cmake
├── Makefile
├── _deps
│   ├── hermes-build
│   ├── hermes-src
│   └── hermes-subbuild
├── bin
│   └── hermes-lit
├── cmake_install.cmake
├── compile_commands.json
└── hello_test[1]_include.cmake
```

then I run `cmake --build build` and see this error

```
/.../test.cpp:8:10: fatal error: 'jsi/jsi.h' file not found
#include <jsi/jsi.h>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is too broad. **Either** ask a question about the list of libraries in cmake, **or** ask a question about how to compile and link with hermes, **or** ask a question about a specific problem with your build about including a third party. These should be 3 separate questions on this site.

> how can I know what are the library name I can link to my target?

There are two things that you can `target_link_libraries` - you can link with libraries available on your system and link with targets defined in cmake.

You can list libraries available on your system by traversing all paths outputted by `ld --verbose` and listing all `lib*.so` files in those directories. Or https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43187/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-shared-library-filenames-under-linux or similar. See `man ld.so`.

You can list all targets defined in cmake. [How do I list the defined make targets from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30793804/how-do-i-list-the-defined-make-targets-from-the-command-line) .

These lists combined consist of all possible libraries names that you can link with.

> Can I tell that from the build file structure

I do not understand. No.

> I need to look into CMakeLists.txt of the external libraries

Yes, usually you *want* to look into any external libraries CMakeLists.txt *at least* to check for malicious code.

You usually look into *documentation* of external libraries. And, because source code *is* a form of documentation in open-source projects, you would look into the source code, yes.

> How can I use a "grandchild" library that is part of the external library?

There are multiple ways for including external projects. Cases were outlined in [Correct way to use third-party libraries in cmake project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51564251/correct-way-to-use-third-party-libraries-in-cmake-project) .

That said, not all CMake projects work properly with `add_subdirectory()` (which is called by `FetchContent_MakeAvailable`) - there are many cases where the third-party projects CMakeLists.txt may not work with parent project. In such cases, I would go with compiling *and installing* the project *into a subdirectory* for example before running CMake or with `ExternalProject_Add`, and then only including the result of compilation with hand-crafted `find_library` and `target_include_directories` from the installation directory.

Overall, including a third party is *not* always an easy task, and *yes* it requires you to become intimate with the specifics of a third party project and how it works and how it was written and decide how you want it to include in your project.