# Retrieve all link flags in CMake

Tags: cmake

In CMake, is it possible to programmatically retrieve the complete list of linker flags that will be used for a given target? The only way I can see to do this is to inspect the `link.txt` file in the target's `CMakeFiles` directory. Not ideal.

The use case that I'm interested in is to collect the data to include in something like a pkg-config file. I'm writing a library, and it includes a couple executable utilities that use the library. Building the executables (especially when the library is build statically) requires a non-trivial link line to link to my library and its dependencies. So I'd like to write out the link line necessary for building these executables to a data file included with the package such that other clients can know how to link.

Comment: If you want more than target's property `LINK_FLAGS` gives, you probably will face with listing all link targets. See, e.g., [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32756195/recursive-list-of-link-libraries-in-cmake). And this problem seems cannot be resolved within CMake script. But you may try generator expression with this property. It may work as using `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` one.

Comment: The possible answers really depend on your motivation. Can you please go a little more into details what you want to do with the flags? E.g. documentation, error tracking, reuse elsewhere, ...

Comment: @Florian: okay, I updated the question with my use case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Tsyvarev has commented there is no build-in command or property *"to programmatically retrieve the complete list of linker flags"* in CMake.

But inspired by your hint *"so I'd like to write out the link line necessary for building these executables to a data file"* I think I found a feasible solution (at least for makefile generators).

And if I understand your request correctly, we are not talking about simple verbose outputs like you get with e.g. [`CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/variable/CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE.html), which would still need you to copy things manually.

So taking the following into account:

- You need to run the generator first to get the real link line
- CMake allows you to invent any linker language by name
- You can define the link line with [CMAKE_>LANG<_LINK_EXECUTABLE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/variable/CMAKE_LANG_LINK_EXECUTABLE.html) using variables and [expansion rules](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables#Expansion_Rules)

I came up with adding an `LinkLine` executable using my `ECHO` "linker" with the single purpose to create a link line file of my choosing:

```
set(CMAKE_ECHO_STANDARD_LIBRARIES ${CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES})
set(CMAKE_ECHO_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS})
set(CMAKE_ECHO_LINK_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS})
set(CMAKE_ECHO_IMPLICIT_LINK_DIRECTORIES ${CMAKE_CXX_IMPLICIT_LINK_DIRECTORIES})
set(
    CMAKE_ECHO_LINK_EXECUTABLE 
    "<CMAKE_COMMAND> -E echo \"<FLAGS> <LINK_FLAGS> <LINK_LIBRARIES>\" > <TARGET>"
)

add_executable(LinkLine "")
target_link_libraries(LinkLine MyLibraryTarget)

set_target_properties(
    LinkLine 
        PROPERTIES
            LINKER_LANGUAGE ECHO
            SUFFIX          ".txt"
)
```

The nice thing about this approach is, that the output of my `LinkLine` target can be used as any other "officially generated" executable output (e.g. in [`install()` commands](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/install.html) or post-build steps with [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html)):

```
add_custom_command(
    TARGET LinkLine
    POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy $<TARGET_FILE:LinkLine> PackageCfg/$<TARGET_FILE_NAME:LinkLine>
)
```

**References**

- [Recursive list of LINK_LIBRARIES in CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32756195/recursive-list-of-link-libraries-in-cmake)
- [add_custom_command is not generating a target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30719275/add-custom-command-is-not-generating-a-target)