# Retrieving the compiler flags from CMake

Tags: cmake

I would like to run a custom command on CMake with the same flags it passes the C++ compiler and linker. Is that possible?

I tried using `get_target_property()` with various properties but nothing I found provided the full set of flags.

Comment: Reading just the ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} and ${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} doesn't work in your case? Which flags are missing?

Comment: These variables don't help because they were overridden by target specific commands like `target_link_libraries()` and `target_compiler_features()`.

Comment: Can you describe more of your intended use case? This is something only the generator can output (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33828855/is-cmake-set-variable-recursive)), so there is something like [`CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS.html). Or maybe something similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34165365/retrieve-all-link-flags-in-cmake) might help.

Comment: I'm using Vivado HLS on my code to convert C++ to verilog, and its compiler gets more or less the same parameters as GCC.